# I run php bin/magento module:enable, page stops loading after that

Tags: magento2, module, setup-di-compile

Fresh install of M2.1 on a Turnkey LAMP (with updated php 5.6 and mysql).

I'm trying to test install a 3rd party module, and one of the commands is:

```
<code>php bin/magento module:enable module1a module1b</code>
```

As soon as I run this command, the website (both front end and admin pages) stop loading.

I then try `"php bin/magento setup:upgrade"` which completes with no errors, I then run `"setup:di:compile"`, and then `"setup:static-content:deploy"` again with no errors.

However, I cannot seem to get the website to load ever again after this.

What am I doing wrong/missing ?

(I'm very new to M2's compile process and correct order of commands).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe there is a problem in your code. Maybe some xml that's not valid. Turn on error reporting and set `display_errors` to `on`.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to flush the cache. `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, after running the initial module:enable several folders in my /var folder became unread/writeable (have no idea how thats possible), but after resetting the access permissions, the website started to load, and everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below setup upgrade command after enable/disable the module:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Enable the one module one time using command below:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Module_Name
```

That may help you!!