# Missing permission in /var folders after enable module

Tags: magento2

Basically, I'm not the only one who has encountered this: [I run php bin/magento module:enable, page stops loading after that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126867/i-run-php-bin-magento-moduleenable-page-stops-loading-after-that) (see the accepted answer by TS)

Does anybody know how/why this happened and how can I fix this? I can always re-set the whole permission again after every enable/disable module but that's annoying.

Comment: Hello @Farid, do you still have issue?

Comment: Nope. Didn't followed exactly what you replied, but it helped me a lot on understanding permission with Linux. Now it's working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm taking reference of apache server in which `www-data` will be the server group. Follow the same for other servers as well.**
This is related to ownership issue. Since you are running `php bin/magento enable:module` as your pc user the files ownership must have changed to `your-user-name:your-user-name` instead of `www-data:www-data` or `your-user-name:www-data`.

To solve this issue you must set group `www-data` as group and you can either place yourself as owner or give complete ownership to `www-data` of magento files. In the case you set yourself as an owner you must add yourself to the server's group i.e. `www-data`.

Next you need to run `find var -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`

What this does is that **all new files and subdirectories created within the current directory inherit the group ID of the directory**, rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the file. **This will also be passed on to new subdirectories created in the current directory.**

I hope this works for you.